# How to get V from HashMap<K, V> so I can get `::BITS` from it?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to make the following function generic. It currently uses `u8::BITS` but I want if a `HashMap<&str, u32>` is passed then use `u32::BITS` instead.

```
fn to_flag<'a>(
    attack: &'a str,
    attack_to_flag: &mut HashMap<&'a str, u8>,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let n = attack_to_flag.len() as u32;
    match n < u8::BITS {
        true => Ok(*attack_to_flag.entry(attack).or_insert(1 << n)),
        false => Err(Box::<dyn Error>::from(
            "More than 8 attacks; u8 insufficient.",
        )),
    }
}
```

In C++ I used to do [`map.mapped_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to get the type. Another approach I tried:

```
fn to_flag<'a, T>(
    attack: &'a str,
    attack_to_flag: &mut HashMap<&'a str, T>,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let n = attack_to_flag.len() as u32;
    match n < T::BITS {
        true => Ok(*attack_to_flag.entry(attack).or_insert(1 << n)),
        false => Err(Box::<dyn Error>::from(
            "More than 8 attacks; u8 insufficient.",
        )),
    }
}
```

But the compiler, understandably, complains

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `BITS` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:41:16
   |
41 |     match n < T::BITS {
   |                  ^^^^ associated item not found in `T`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:42:56
   |
36 | fn to_flag<'a, T>(
   |                - this type parameter
...
42 |         true => Ok(*attack_to_flag.entry(attack).or_insert(1 << n)),
   |                                                  --------- ^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found integer
   |                                                  |
   |                                                  arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `{integer}`
```

I was unable to find an `Integer` trait. What are my options?

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the title and the content of the question, tbh. Where are you trying to get a HashMap's value type? Getting it is easy, your actual question is how to derive `BITS` from it. That's the hard part.

Comment: @Finomnis I've taken the template/generic approach to attack the problem.  However, if `to_flag` is a simple function, how do we get the `u8` in `HashMap<&str, u8>`?  I.e. if I simply change the function param type to say `u16`, the code in body which does `u8::BITS` should change change to `u16::BITS`.  In C++ we'd do `map.mapped_type::BITS`.

Comment: Well, `T` is your type in your function. I'd qualify that as "getting it". The problem is that Rust is a lot more typesafe than C++. C++'s templating system is basically duck typing, and it can then fail when in actually instantiate the template. Rust is more typesafe, if you manage to write the template, it will always instantiate correctly. But that means you need to add constraints to your template type to tell Rust what kind of types it should expect. As detailed in @Chayim's answer.

Comment: @Finomnis I understand that part.  I didn't want to make it a templatized function but rather, if I change the function parameter type, I want the code in body to automatically adapt. Perhaps this is disallowed in Rust, not sure.  This approach, which is the question title, is still unanswered.

Comment: I think in that case your question becomes very context dependent. You can always resolve the map type into its value type by passing it into a template function. That's how type resolution is usually done in Rust. For example, to get the size of the variable in bytes, do this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8356082b6061affa5365147561a5eef. This one only works, though, because every type can do `size_of`. If you want something more specific, you have to introduce trait restrictions for your template type.

Comment: @Finomnis This is a valid answer IMHO.  If you don't mind please post it as one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits) crate contains a lot of numeric traits, including for example [`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/int/trait.PrimInt.html). However, [it doesn't contains a trait for `BITS`](https://github.com/rust-num/num-traits/issues/247).

You can easily create a trait that has a `BITS` constant:

```rust
trait Bits {
  const BITS: usize;
}
macro_rules! impl_bits {
  ( $($ty:ident)* ) => {
    $(
      impl Bits for $ty {
        const BITS: usize = Self::BITS as usize;
      }
    )*
  };
}
impl_bits!(u8 u16 u32 u64 u128);
```

Then

```rust
fn to_flag<'a, T: Bits + PrimInt>(
  attack: &'a str,
  attack_to_flag: &mut HashMap<&'a str, T>,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let n = attack_to_flag.len();
  let mask = T::one() << n;
  match n < T::BITS {
    true => Ok(*attack_to_flag.entry(attack).or_insert(mask)),
    false => Err(Box::<dyn Error>::from(
      "More than 8 attacks; u8 insufficient.",
    )),
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was hoping to get away without external crates but this is a good approach nevertheless.

Comment: @legends2k You can constrain `Shl` directly.

Comment: Added `T::one()` to your answer since without that the compiler still complains `expected type parameter `T`, found integer`.

Comment: You don't need a macro to implement `Bits`, a blanket implementation will do: `impl<T> Bits for T { const BITS: usize = std::mem::size_of::<T>() * 8; }`. Or you can just use `std::mem::size_of::<T>() * 8` instead of `T::BITS` to begin with.

Comment: @user4815162342 Are bytes guaranteed to be 8 bits in Rust?  Sorry if this sounds like a trick/silly question but the reason I ask is (a) _why is there a `u8::BITS` if it's always going to be 8_?  (b) In C++ and some architectures [a byte is not necessarily 8 bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof), being a C++ programmer, I'm conditioned by it.

Comment: Yes. A `u8` is defined to be an 'unsigned integer of size 8 bits'. That's what the name says. It's similar to `uint8_t` in C++, which is also guaranteed to be 8 bits. What you are talking about is a C++ problem which should have never happened in the first place, in my opinion. That's why Rust doesn't have an `int` type; all of Rust's types are fixed size types. (Except `usize`, which is of course platform dependent on purpose)

Comment: The reason why `u8::BITS` exists is the same reason why `u8::MAX` exists, although it is always going to be the same value of `255`. To make the code people write more expressive and with less magic numbers.

Comment: Actually, scrap that. While it's true that `u8` is guaranteed to be always of size `8`, I don't think it's the value returned by `size_of()` is always in increments of 8 bits. But I'm not entirely sure, might need someone with more experience.

Comment: There's a more detailed discussion about this [in the rust language issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62836).

Comment: @legends2k Not sure if it counts as guarantee, but the [std::mem::size_of docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) clearly say that `u8` has a size of 1, and `u8` is [explicitly designated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html) as the 8-bit integer type. And even if there were no official "guarantee", the entire ecosystem certainly expects 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 2):

One question you ask is how to get the value type of a `HashMap`.

Usually, in Rust, this is done by type destructuring through templates:

```rust
fn do_something<K, V>(_m: &HashMap<K, V>) {
    // `V` is the value type, do something with it if desired
}
```

Using this mechanism, we could write a function that returns the size of the value type:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_size_of_value<K, V>(_m: &HashMap<K, V>) -> usize {
    std::mem::size_of::<V>()
}

fn main() {
    let m = HashMap::<String, u16>::new();
    println!("Size of value type: {} bytes", get_size_of_value(&m));
}
```

```
Size of value type: 2 bytes
```

As this funciton doesn't even depend on the input *value*, only its type, there is a very high chance that this method will be evaluated at compile time and inlined, giving you zero performance overhead.

Of course, this only works because all types can be passed into `std::mem::size_of`. If you desire to do something more type-specific, you might have to specify trait restrictions to your `V` template type.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to aproach these types of problems.

Note that @Chayim's answer is basically the same thing. Just instead of using a separate function, he used the `to_flag` function itself to destructure the type via a template; and instead of using `size_of`, he used a custom `BITS` wrapper. But the underlying principle is identical.